# Good vs bad tasting oil for menorah

Tags: halacha, food, menora-chanukia, taste

Is there any halachik benefit or hiddur to using a better tasting oil for the Chanukah menorah?

Comment: This question would be stronger if you would [edit] in something about why you think there may be such a benefit.

Answer (score 1):

The halacha is its better to use olive oil (see רמ''א שו''ע או''ח ס' תרעג) because menorah is a zecher for bais hamikdash. in the bais hamikdash they used only the first drop because it was the highest quality and best tasting.
It would than be sensible to conclude that for the same reason we should use the best quality/tasting oil. see לבוש תרע''ג

Comment: _Rama_ there says olive oil is best but doesn't say why. Can you source your claim that olive oil's preference is to remember the _mikdash_, or your claim that taste was part of the reason for the choice of oil in the _mikdash_?